# Getting branch,subject,status from Python-gerrit-api package

Tags: python, gerrit

**Documentation link:https://python-gerrit-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html**

**Code:**

gerrit=GerritClient(base_url="https://gerrit.xx.xxx.com",username='xxx',password='xxx')

change = gerrit.changes.get("xxx")

**Question**

I get the GerritChange object(change) from the above code and how do I print status, branch, project, etc.. from this object?

Comment: I was going to say this is obsolete, but that was pygerrit vs pygerrit2.. https://github.com/dpursehouse/pygerrit2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple test I just did. Looks like a nice api. Thanks, may use it myself.

See: https://python-gerrit-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/gerrit/changes/change.html#GerritChange

```
from gerrit import GerritClient
gerrit = GerritClient(base_url="https://gerrit.xxx.xxx", username='xxx', password='xxxx')

change = gerrit.changes.get("7268")

print (change.branch)
print (change.project)
print (change.status)
# The current_revision is not returned when loading a change
print (change.current_revision)

resultset = gerrit.changes.search("q=7268&o=CURRENT_REVISION")
change = resultset[0]

# The current_revision is returned when searching
# and adding the CURRENT_REVISION option
print (change.current_revision)

# Use the current revision to display the files
revision = change.get_revision(change.current_revision)
for f in revision.files:
  print (f)
```

Comment: Thank you very much appreciate it.For some endpoints, I am able to send get responses from the rest api but via this package I get this error(gerrit.utils.exceptions.NotFoundError: 404 Client Error).
I am able to get response from Get Rest api for this url: https://gerrit.xx.xx.com/a/projects/xxxx/commits/xxxx/files/ via postman.

Code:
ab=change.get_revision("32423")

print(ab.get_commit().list_change_files())

I get error for this code.

Comment: The parameter in get_revision should be the SHA-1 of that commit

Comment: It is not easy to find the current_revision using the Gerrit API. The only way I could find it is using the search function. https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#current-revision

Comment: Yes I did use SHA-1 I just mentioned this no here.Still I get 404 Client Error while I am able to get response from Rest API for the same.I asked another question about the same .Please can you have a look at it.